# How to avoid date time change on refresh after displaying once?

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime

I have a function that gets the current date time and add 30 minutes to it in the controller. I'm sending that data into the view and displaying it.

Controller

```
public function index(){
$data['time'] = $this->set_time();

$this->load->view('templates/location_header');
$this->load->view('pages/confirmation', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
}

public function set_time(){
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Colombo');
$time = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime('+30 minute'));

    return $time;
}
```

View

```
<h5 class= "order-time"> Your order will arrive in : <?php echo $time ?></h5>
```

My question is, can i make the date/time displayed in the view fixed so that whenever i refresh it will stay at the original date/time returned?
For example when i load the page first time the returned date/time is `2020/11/09 10:30`.
If i refresh the page again in 5 minutes how can i keep the time `2020/11/09 10:30` instead of getting `2020/11/09 10:35`.

Thank you.

Comment: Your real question is - How can I make a variable persistent across pages? And the answer is to use Sessions. So read up on how to use CI Sessions.

Comment: You could use sessions as @TimBrownlaw stated or, if this time is not session dependent but related to an order, you could save the future date to the database along with the rest of the order data.  What exactly is your case?

Comment: The time in fact is related to the order. Even if i use the session the value still changes when i manually reload the page. The reloading is just for test purposes as there's no auto refreshing pages. I simply want to make the initial date fixed. I feel like saving to a database would be the best option if there's no other way. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add this line to your the first line of your php files to use the session

```php
session_start();
```

Then you can use the session in this way

```php
public function index(){
$data['time'] = $this->set_time();

$this->load->view('templates/location_header');
$this->load->view('pages/confirmation', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
}

public function set_time(){
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Colombo');
$time = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime('+30 minute'));
$_SESSION['time'] = $time;
$_SESSION['start'] = time(); // Taking now logged in time.
// Ending a session in 30 minutes from the starting time.
$_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (30 * 60);
    return $time;
}
```

And do something like this in your view

```html
<h5 class= "order-time"> Your order will arrive in : 
<?php 
if (time() > $_SESSION['expire']) {
    session_destroy();
    echo $time;
} else {
    echo $_SESSION['time'];
}
?>
</h5>
```

And you can change the time that you want to be the persist with changing the "(30 * 60)"

I hope my solution solves your problem

Comment: using `session_start()` (and anything that's not native Codeigniter session management) is not really a good idea. While in essence your recommendation is sound, I'd use codeigniter's session library to avoid problems

Comment: My implementation is done without using any global variables and session is already in use for displaying the cart though I appreciate the answer

Answer (score 0):

First in your controller start the session at first line of PHP :
`session_start();`

Then store your data in session like :

```
if( empty($_SESSION['time']) ) {

  $_SESSION['time'] = date('Y-m-d H:i');

}
```

Then in your view show it like :

```
<h5><?php echo $_SESSION['time']; ?></h5>
```

or

```
<h5><?=$_SESSION['time']?></h5>
```

[How can I make a variable persistent across pages?](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)